Hi, I am trying to install flatpak and i got these errors
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 flatpak : Depends: libmalcontent-0-0 (>= 0.6.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libostree-1-1 (>= 2020.8) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried sudo apt --fix-missing update
but it didnt work pls help

Please edit your question to include the complete output of sudo apt update and of apt policy libmalcontent-0-0

Does this answer your question? 'held on to broken packages' - Steam
